# iOS 10 Core Data Exception Code error: (6922)

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, swift3, core-data-migration

We're experiencing an exception from our SQL database while trying to migrate Core Data on iOS 10. The exception is thrown but it seems the migration still succeeds. We do a manual migration then MagicalRecord handles the rest of the setup. Has anyone else experienced this before/ knows how to resolve this?

Error output:

```
    CoreData: error: (6922) I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9CA333FB-49CB-4168-B26A-A6F6E6CF94C7/Documents/Messaging.sqlite.  SQLite error code:6922, 'disk I/O error'
CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9CA333FB-49CB-4168-B26A-A6F6E6CF94C7/Documents/Messaging.sqlite options:{
NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
NSSQLitePragmasOption =     {
    "journal_mode" = WAL;
};
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file couldn't be opened." UserInfo={NSSQLiteErrorDomain=6922, NSUnderlyingException=I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9CA333FB-49CB-4168-B26A-A6F6E6CF94C7/Documents/Messaging.sqlite.  SQLite error code:6922, 'disk I/O error'} with userInfo dictionary {
NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 6922;
NSUnderlyingException = "I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9CA333FB-49CB-4168-B26A-A6F6E6CF94C7/Documents/Messaging.sqlite.  SQLite error code:6922, 'disk I/O error'";
}
CoreData: error: Illegal attempt to save to a file that was never opened.  "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (I/O error).  It cannot perform a save operation.".  Last recorded error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file "Messaging.sqlite" couldn't be opened." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9CA333FB-49CB-4168-B26A-A6F6E6CF94C7/Documents/Messaging.sqlite, NSSQLiteErrorDomain=6922} / {
NSFilePath = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9CA333FB-49CB-4168-B26A-A6F6E6CF94C7/Documents/Messaging.sqlite";
NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 6922;
}
```

Comment: hey were you able to resolve the problem? Can you check out the solution I've proposed?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue today after upgrading to Xcode 11 beta 5.

Running the command to reset all of my simulators corrected it for me:

```
xcrun simctl erase all
```

Comment: @Karaban Regarding my experience, it could be related to simulator changes since there were other issues associated with them. No changes were made to the app to explain an incompatibility.